# Uninstall rEFInd 0.8-3.7 on Yosemite

Tags: startup, macos, dual-boot, efi

I recently tried installing rEFInd on Yosemite using the command `./install.sh --alldrivers` however it would not recognise the ubuntu 14.04 x64 for Mac disk I made and so I would like to uninstall rEFInd.

I have tried removing rEFInd from the EFI directory, however the EFI directory does not exist. How do I uninstall rEFInd 0.8-3.7 using OS X 10.10.3?

**Edit**
Here are my drives if this helps (found using `diskutil list`

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            235.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data Linux                   15.0 GB    disk0s4
```

Ignore `disk0s4` because I am going to remove it (that is where my Linux partition would have been)

Comment: The author of rEFInd recommends not to uninstall, but rather to bypass it. See [Uninstalling rEFInd from OS X](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#uinst_osx).

Comment: If rEFInd did not work, then how are you booting ubuntu.?

Comment: @DavidAnderson I said I cannot dual boot it. because it wouldn't boot into the disk. I am now running it on Virtual Box

Comment: @DavidAnderson that bypass worked for me. How would I go and reinstall it using different options if I cannot remove it? Could I simply remove the EFI partition or would that corrupt my Mac?

Comment: "I have tried removing rEFInd from the EFI directory, however the EFI directory does not exist." You have to mount the EFI partition into a directory, first. This is what the answer of davidcondrey does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Note: El Capitan (OS X 10.11) prevents users from selecting rEFInd and common Linux distributions from the Startup Disk pane.** The new preferred method is to install rEFInd into the an EFI partition. My [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235442/mysterious-efi-boot-partition-appearing-at-startup/235505#235505), to an unrelated question, outlines this new preferred method to start the rEFInd Boot Manager and Linux operating systems. The answer, given below, applies to Yosemite (OS X 10.10) and possibly earlier versions of OS X.

Personally, I installed rEFInd on my computer to its own partition. This prevents the problems you are encountering. Everything `./install.sh` installed went to this partition. If I want to remove rEFInd, I can simply erase or remove the partition. Of course both are unnecessary, because I can turn rEFInd on and off at will. I just go to the Startup window in System Preferences select my boot partition. This computer has OS X, Windows, Fedora and rEFInd installed.

[image: 2]

I also can select the boot partition under Windows by using BootCamp and by holding the Option key down at startup. The command `diskutil list` produces:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Marlin                  300.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data Coelacanth              98.9 GB    disk0s4
   5:                  Apple_HFS Linux HFS+ ESP          209.7 MB   disk0s5
   6: 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4               524.3 MB   disk0s6
   7:                  Linux LVM                         98.6 GB    disk0s7
   8:                  Apple_HFS rEFInd                  939.5 MB   disk0s8
```

Note, the rEFInd partition is ~ 1 GB in size. In fact, it can be as small as 100 MB. When I setup this computer, I used the Disk Utility application to create the rEFInd partition. If I would have used the `gpt` command, I could have created a smaller partition. Neither OS X, Windows, Fedora nor rEFInd use the EFI partition to boot the computer. In fact, there is nothing useful in the EFI partition.

### Answer to your questions:

**How do I uninstall rEFInd 0.8-3.7 using OS X 10.10.3?** Read the `./install.sh` file and undo whatever it did. I should of had you run the commands `bless --info` and `bless --info  --getBoot`. These would have told where the `.efi` file was stored. Note: Almost everyone installs rEFInd to the OS X boot partition.

**How would I go and reinstall it using different options if I cannot remove it?** The author of the software never said rEFInd could not be removed. I suggested you just install it again to its own partition. This might be a good place to mention the `gpt` command has to be run while either booted to an external recover partition or while booted to internet recovery.

**Could I simply remove the EFI partition or would that corrupt my Mac?** Do not remove the EFI partition! It is not used to boot OS X, but it is used by OS X for *other* things.

Comment: I'm going to do what you did. Insta rEFInd onto another partition. To remove it I am reinstalling OS X. Also what is the EFI partition used for?

Comment: Adding this here on behalf of @Jerry http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/137606/jerry  

"Your OS setup sounds great. Do you mind sharing a little more about creating the rEFInd partition and setup? I would like to avoid rEFInd from becoming the primary bootloader."

Answer (score 2):

```
diskutil list | grep EFI | awk '{print $6}'
```

This will only output the lines of containing the string "efi" and of that line, only the 6th column, so the output is:

```
disk0s1
```

You already did this part it looks like your EFI disk is disk0s1

```
sudo mkdir /Volumes/efi
sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/efi
sudo rm -rfP /Volumes/efi/EFI/refind

sudo bless --setBoot --mount /
```